# Self-Signing Java Applets

Tags: java, jar, applet

I'm having troubling self-signing a Java applet. The applet consists of just one class called TestApplet and works correctly inside the Eclipse applet viewer. The applet is packaged into a jar file which is signed using a keystore.

```
jarsigner -keystore ..\.keystore bin\TestApplet.jar myalias
```

which outputted "jar signed"
And a warning message: "The signer certificate will expire within 6 months"

I uploaded the files to a public web page and ran the applet within a web browser but received an error message: "Application Blocked by Security Settings" and cannot run the applet. If I change Security Level to Medium I get a warning message: "An unsigned application from the location below is requesting permission to run." and I can get the applet to run. But the applet needs to run on other computers so this solution is inadequate.

If I download the jar file from the host I can verify it.

```
jarsigner -verify TestApplet.jar
```

which outputted "jar verified"

So why does the jar file appear to be unsigned when ran from within a web browser but signed when checked with jarsigner?

The only thing I can think of is that TestApplet.jar is being ignored completely. It is possible to run the applet without specifying the archive parameter.

Here is the structure of the files.

```
bin/TestApplet.class
bin/TestApplet.jar
index.html
```

Here is the code I use to add the java applet to the web page.

```
<object type="application/x-java-applet" width="100" height="100">
  <param name="codebase" value="bin" />
  <param name="archive" value="bin/TestApplet.jar" />
  <param name="code" value="TestApplet" />
</object>
```

**EDIT:**
If it makes any difference, the applets will be run on a local network that isn't connected to the internet.

Comment: Most browsers consider 'unsigned' and 'self signed' to be the same thing, since they have no way of verifying that you are who you say you are with a self-signed cert.

Comment: Unsigned and self-signed JARs have more or less been deprecated by Oracle.  Using default security settings the only way to run applets in the browser now is to sign them using a real CA.

Comment: Here's one source of their security announcement: https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/new_security_requirements_for_rias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Self signed applets are not trusted anymore. You need to sign your jars with a code signing certificate issued by a Trusted CA.

The reason why jarsigner says **jar verified** is because it is indeed signed correctly and fulfill one of the signature purpose, which is to assure integrity. It makes sure that your jar was not modified, which is ok when distributing your jar, just not in the context of an applet, where we also need to know that it came from a trusted source.